# Why sometimes completion handler not called?

Tags: ios, swift

The problem is that *sometimes* (not always) my completion handler become nil.

I've already tried [weak self] but it doesn't work.

```swift
func setup() {
 _collectionView.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

```
 @objc private func refresh(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
       print("request1")
       request(refresh: true, completion: { () -> Void in
           // When completion become nil, this is not called.
           (sender as UIRefreshControl).endRefreshing()
           print("completion1")
       })
   }


   fileprivate func request(refresh: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

       guard !isFetchInProgress else {
           return
       }
       isFetchInProgress = true

       APIRequest.request(request: request).success { [weak self] result in
           Log.debugLog(“success!:%@“, result)
               if let _self = self {
                   if RequestResponseManager.sharedInstance.handleResponse(response: result) {
                        if let _data = result.data {
                         print(_data)
                   }
               }
           }.failure { error, _ in
               Log.debugLog(“%@“, error.debugDescription)
               completion?()
               isFetchInProgress = false
           }.then { _,_  in
               Log.debugLog(“then!“)    

               // SOMETIMES (not always) completion?() become nil
               completion?()
               isFetchInProgress =false
           }
   }
```

```
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        var target: UICollectionReusableView? = nil
  if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter {
            target = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: footerId, for: indexPath)

            if isNeedRequest {
                print("request2")
                self.request(refresh: false)
            }
        }

        return target!
    }
```

1、When scroll down & up speed is normal, log shows the below and that's fine.

```
request1
completion1
request2
```

2、However when scroll down & up speed is faster, log shows the below and never called completion1 and stopped refreshControl.

```
request1
request2
```

I wonder how I can handle it properly?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the APIRequest always finishes? For example: When `isFetchInProgress` is true, the API request never even starts and the completion handler is never called.

Comment: Looks like in this case `completion` is strongly referenced and may not in any case be set to `nil`, not even explicitly. The only way this is `nil` because it is already injected as `nil`. Ergo somewhere something is calling `request(refresh: flag, completion: nil)`.

Comment: @wvteijlingen Thank you for your comment. debugLog is always showed  either . failure or .then

Comment: @MaticOblak Thank you for your reply. Actually `request(refresh: false)` is called from other method when the collectionView is scrolled to the end. 
How can I avoid  `@objc private func refresh(sender: UIRefreshControl)` `completion ` is injected  as nil?

Comment: @Alea could you please add that code as well?

Comment: @MaticOblak Yes, I added some code. Thanks

Comment: @Alea what about “requestProduct” method?

Comment: @MaticOblak Sorry, I edited. It also calls  `fileprivate func request(refresh: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)`

Comment: @Alea so from this edit you got to the situation as already mentioned by matt in his answer; You call self.request(refresh: false) which uses default completion that is nil.

Comment: @MaticOblak Yes, I understand when I call `self.request(refresh: false)` then return nil and that's fine. However when I call `request(refresh: true, completion: { () -> Void in ` sometimes `completion` not called as I edited 2nd log. so I wonder why it's not called.

Comment: @Alea I don't think that could be the case. Just to test you can duplicate your method and remove the default value for `completion`. One method has completion and the other one does not. Now see if the one with completion can ever get a `nil` value for completion. You can even make it non-optional and compiler will warn you if you somewhere failed to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The completion handler does not "become" nil. It is `nil` by default if no completion handler is supplied at the time the method is called.

Your method is declared

```
fileprivate func request(refresh: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

This means that in effect there are two ways of calling this method. You can call it with a completion handler:

```
request(refresh: true) {
    // this is the completion handler
}
```

or

```
request(refresh: false) {
    // this is the completion handler
}
```

But you can also call it *without* a completion handler:

```
request(refresh: true)
```

or

```
request(refresh: false)
```

In that case, inside your `request` method, `completion` will be `nil`. So if you don't want `completion` to be `nil`, don't do that.